# Obter nome do domínio dinamicamente no arquvo htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Possuo um arquivo .htaccess com diversas instruções. Gostaria de torná-lo mais dinâmico, isto é, deixá-lo mais otimizado para outros sites sem precisar editá-lo.

Linhas como as citadas abaixo fazem referência ao nome do domínio, gostaria então que ele buscasse o nome do domínio automaticamente, sem a necessidade de citá-lo.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 
http://www.nomedodominio.com.br/diretorio/administrador/$1 
[R=301,L]
```

e

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.nomedodominio.com.br/diretorio/administrador/
```

Obs: Preciso manter o caminho após o nome do domínio: 
 **/diretorio/administrador/**.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Temos uma quantidade absurda de postagens sobre htaccess no site, praticamente cobrindo quase todas as situações comuns, seria bom uma pesquisada. Isto que você está querendo é o normal, o que não é normal é o domínio estar "hardcoded" como no seu exemplo (pra começo de conversa, as linhas não precisariam ter o domínio referido).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta remover o dominio, o rewriterule só precisará se realmente quiser mudar de domino, o mesmo vale para o `ErrorDocument`, no caso bastaria fazer isto:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /diretorio/administrador/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /diretorio/administrador/
```

Lembre-se, a barra na frente `/` indica a pasta raiz nos redirecionamentos e no `ErrorDocument` indica a localização do arquivo no teu `VirtualHost`

Comment: Muito obrigado!